# Fab and Button Size

Tags: android, android-studio

In the android studio when I try to increase the layout size to **75dp** or so,  the play **button(Fab**) becomes small and *misaligned* i.e. it doesn't look like it fits in the center of the button.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you xml:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Note: you can't change the drawable size, so the best way to fix it is to add an image view beside it

Comment: Try this:                       android:layout_gravity="center"                       if it won't work share your .xml file